# keep some lines of a file according to some conditions

Tags: bash, while-loop, grep, line

I have a file of that kind :

```
K1   bla   STARTED
K1   bla   FINISHED
K2   blu   FINISHED
K3   bli   STARTED
K3   bli   DIED_SKIPPED_PERMANENTLY
K4   blo   STARTED
K5   ble   STARTED
K5   ble   DIED_SKIPPED_PERMANENTLY
K6   blou  STARTED
K6   blou  STARTED
```

From this, I want to obtain a file where, when for each name in column 1 there is `FINISHED` or `DIED_SKIPPED_PERMANENTLY`, only the line containing this information is present and not the other ones (with STARTED or other things).
Moreover, if two lines are identical (like the one of K6), I want to print only one.

With my example, the output would be:

```
K1   bla   FINISHED
K2   blu   FINISHED
K3   bli   DIED_SKIPPED_PERMANENTLY
K4   blo   STARTED
K5   ble   DIED_SKIPPED_PERMANENTLY
K6   blou  STARTED
```

I can't only delete by

```
grep -v STARTED
```

because for some names, like K4 in my example, only this line is present and I want to know that it started (or not) so I need to keep that info.

I have a file with all the names from column 1 that I obtained with:

```
awk '{print $1}' file | sort | uniq > names    # 7,752 lines
```

I was thinking about a loop of that kind:

For each names present in the file "names", do:

If one of the line with $`line` contains `FINISHED` or `DIED_SKIPPED_PERMANENTLY`, then print only that line in my output and don't print the others.
Else, keep all the lines containing that name.
But delete the lines that are identical.

Here is the idea, but I don't know how I can do this.
I would appreciate if someone could help

Comment: `only the line containing this information is present and not the other ones (with STARTED or other things)` but your output do have `STARTED`? what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

We can use the fact that `STARTED` is lexicographically greater than both `FINISHED` and `DIED_SKIPPED_PERMANENTLY` and use

```
sort filename | awk '!seen[$1,$2]++'
```

Because `STARTED` is lexicographically greatest, a `STARTED` line will always appear after a `FINISHED` or `DIED_SKIPPED_PERMANENTLY` line when `sort` is done. The awk code wades through the so sorted lines and prints only those where it hasn't seen the combination of fields 1 and 2 before.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk and arrays

```
awk '!a[$1]||/DIED_SKIPPED_PERMANENTLY|FINISHED/{a[$1]=$0}END{for(i in a)print a[i]}' f
```

Output

```
K1   bla   FINISHED
K2   blu   FINISHED
K3   bli   DIED_SKIPPED_PERMANENTLY
K4   blo   STARTED
K5   ble   DIED_SKIPPED_PERMANENTLY
K6   blou  STARTED
```

Note this is to get the expected output you have posted, but won't work for the actual description.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$3 ~ /FINISHED|DIED_SKIPPED_PERMANENTLY/ && !a[$0]++' input
```

This simply checks if the 3rd column matches either FINISHED or DIED_SKIPPED_PERMANENTLY and stores the full line in the array `a`, printing it only the first time it is seen.  Note that this will print lines which contain 'FOO_FINISHED" the third column, but that shouldn't be an issue.  However, given the provided sample output, I think you are actually looking for:

```
awk '$1!=p && NR>1{print l}; {p=$1;l=$0}END{ if($1!=p)print l}' input
```

which prints the last line in which a given field occurs in column 1, when the keys in column 1 appear contiguously.

Comment: This doesn't print started lines, also there is a stray `/` at the end

Comment: No, it does not print lines matching 'STARTED'.  It matches the description given in the question rather than the provided output, which is inconsistent.